# Proper sequence for JOIN, UNION, Repalce NULLs, CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am running this query in phpMyAdmin on my Bluehost site.

The following query properly returns four columns, the last of which contains either a company_name from the JOIN table (ticker_list) or a NULL if the database.name did not equal a ticker_list.ticker. Can I add to this query code that will replace all of the NULLs in column 4 (company_name) with the string in the second column (name)? Equally acceptable would be a new column. Thanks to anyone who responds.

```
SELECT start_date, name, EVENT, ticker_list.company_name
FROM 2015_database 
LEFT JOIN ticker_list
ON 2015_database.name = ticker_list.ticker

UNION

SELECT start_date, name, EVENT,ticker_list.company_name
FROM 2016_database
LEFT JOIN ticker_list
ON 2016_database.name=ticker_list.ticker
```

Comment: You also have `sql-server` tagged.

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for separate years? :-(

Comment: 2015 frozen, 2016 updated weekly; I am about to edit this post so don't anyone spend time on it until I post my edit; I may have been able to solve my own problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
SELECT start_date, name, EVENT, IsNull(ticker_list.company_name,name) as company_name
FROM 2015_database 
LEFT JOIN ticker_list
ON 2015_database.name = ticker_list.ticker

UNION

SELECT start_date, name, EVENT, IsNull(ticker_list.company_name,name) as company_name
FROM 2016_database
LEFT JOIN ticker_list
ON 2016_database.name=ticker_list.ticker
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Slava_Murygin I could not get this to work, but thanks.  I rewrote the code to accomplish what I need in three distinct queries and will put up a new post asking if they can be combined into a single query.